# Is val_sample_weights broken in tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

I cannot seem to make `val_sample_weights` work with validation data, using `model.fit()`. 
My understanding of `val_sample_weights` is that it is suppose to do exactly the same as `sample_weight` such that reported `loss` and `val_loss` can be directly compared when training using `sample_weight`.

From my example code below, we see that `loss` goes to zero when setting `sample_weight` to zero, but `val_loss` is unaffected when setting `val_sample_weights` to zero.

Am I missing or misunderstanding something here, or does this seem like `val_sample_weights` has no use in `tf.keras`? Maybe a bug in `tf.keras`? I'm on Windows, tensorflow version 1.14.0.

Below is a working example if you want to test it yourself:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data_size = 100
input_size=3
seed = 1

# synetic train data
x_train = np.random.rand(data_size ,input_size)
y_train= np.random.rand(data_size,1)
# synetic test data
x_test = np.random.rand(data_size ,input_size)
y_test= np.random.rand(data_size,1)

tf.random.set_random_seed(seed)
# create model
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(input_size))
pred=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=pred)
loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE
metrics = tf.keras.losses.MAE
model.compile(loss=loss , metrics=[metrics], optimizer='adam')

# Make model static, so we can compare it between different scenarios
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# base model no weights (same result as without class_weights)
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test))
# which outputs:
#> 100/100 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.0851 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2511 - val_loss: 0.0900 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2629

#changing the sample_weights to zero, Hence loss and val_loss should be zero, and metrics should be the same
sample_weight_train = np.zeros(100)
sample_weight_val = np.zeros(100)
model.fit(x=x_train,y=y_train,sample_weight=sample_weight_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test,sample_weight_val))
# which outputs:
#> 100/100 [==============================] - 0s 860us/sample - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2507 - val_loss: 0.0899 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.2627
```